# MinGW g++ instantly deletes compiled exe

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, windows-10

I've just installed MinGW with mingw32-base and mingw32-gcc-g++ on Windows 10 and added "C:\MinGW\bin\" to the system path and I can run gcc and g++ from the command prompt, but when I try to compile a .cpp file with `g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe` it creates helloworld.exe and after about 2 seconds it deletes helloworld.exe. If I try to run `helloworld.exe` from the prompt before it deletes it, it gives me "Access is denied.".

Here is helloworld.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

But even if I use other code it does the same.

Comment: It may be done not by g++ but by your security (anti-virus) software.

Comment: It was my antivirus software (avast) and I just had it on silent mode because of annoying promotions... I already know I'm gonna get a bunch of downvotes... :/